# Using PHP exec() to run binary from environment variable

Tags: php, ubuntu, environment-variables, binaryfiles, shell-exec

From a PHP script I need to execute a binary which is linked in the environment variable. The binary is on a Ubuntu Server and the PHP script on the Server is called via HTTP.

However, using

```
<?php
echo exec("MyProgram -C");
?>
```

doesn't execute anything. `MyProgram` should write something in an external textfile so I am sure it has not been executed.

I tested also with the absolute directory to the binary

```
<?php
echo exec("/absolute/path/to/MyProgram -C");
?>
```

but still nothing is executed.

Also `exec()` doesn't return any output and other similar php-functions such as `passthru()`, behave the same. How can I execute this binary from PHP? What is going wrong here?

**EDIT:**

running

```
sudo -u www-data MyProgram -C
```

returns in the terminal

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cIOException'
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Where does this error come from?

Comment: Have you tried to add the output parameter and echo that to see if it contains the data? `exec('path', $output); var_dump($output);`

Comment: Have you tried running the program from the command line? Are you sure php (or the user that your server is running under) has the execute permission on the program?

Comment: Its an apache server, so the user should be www. The command works fine when I run it over a ssh. The strange thing is it doesn't give any output when running exec(), not even an error

Comment: I found out running sudo -u www-data MyProgram -C returns cIOException aborted (core dumped)

Comment: I have exactly the same problem right now. Does anybody have an idea?